# Laravel - Using of yields / extends

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, include

I have an @include problem with my bootstrap navbar. I worked on it this morning and I really don't know where the problem is.

Here is the error message :

**View [layouts.navbar] not found.**

I want to include the content of **navbar.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mana Tournaments</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
{!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}
{!! Html::style ('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')  !!}
{!! Html::style ('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') !!}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="welcome">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tournois</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inscription</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To my index page (**welcome.blade.php**)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Mana Tournaments</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    {!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}
    {!! Html::style ('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')  !!}
    {!! Html::style ('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') !!}
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Gestionnaire de tournois</h1>
<div class="container">
 @include('layouts.navbar')
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I created manually a layout folder, then i created the navbar file. If I did someting wrong, maybe there's a command line for laravel for creating a folder ?

Thank you for helping me on my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

Make sure the view you're including exists in the correct folder.

`@include('layouts.navbar')` will include that path `\resources\views\layouts\navbar.blade.php`

**Make sure, The file within layouts directory,**

**Second**, You don't need to write the whole html for the included part. 
navbar.blade.php will be added (included) to welcome.blade.php, 
 it's like you're copying the content of `navbar.blade.php` and adding it to `welcome.blade.php`,

So make it like this instead,

navbar.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="welcome">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tournois</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inscription</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am an idiot. Thanks for the help but I'm not proud of that mistake. I learnt a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That's because that file is not in the app/views directory. When you call `@include('filename')`, Blade automatically looks for any file with that name, inside the apps/views directory. Also, you're not supposed to write the file extension, as Blade automatically looks for files with .blade.php and .php extensions.

**For Laravel 5** use this folder

```
resources/views/
```